# Sendmail to Google Apps domain relay

Tags: sendmail, gmail, email

The site I manage has email configured on Google Apps. So, all email accounts are there. I therefore don't want to have my local senmail accept mail for my domain. Instead, if should send it to gmail.  I have put the following at the end of sendmail.mc and recompiled sendmail.cf:

```
define(LUSER_RELAY,`aspmx3.googlemail.com')dnl
```

However, I'm getting the following error still:

```
Jul  2 22:47:23 culinaryhalloffame sendmail[21267]: p632lNDk021267: from=apache, size=753, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<13096612437327@culinarybytes.com>, relay=apache@localhost
Jul  2 22:47:23 culinaryhalloffame sendmail[21270]: p632lNkV021270: from=<apache@culinaryhalloffame.com>, size=851, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<13096612437327@culinarybytes.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Jul  2 22:47:23 culinaryhalloffame sendmail[21267]: p632lNDk021267: to=recluze@culinaryhalloffame.com, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30753, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (p632lNkV021270 Message accepted for delivery)
Jul  2 22:47:24 culinaryhalloffame sendmail[21272]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx3.googlemail.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Jul  2 22:47:27 culinaryhalloffame sendmail[21272]: p632lNkV021270: to=<recluze@culinaryhalloffame.com>, ctladdr=<apache@culinaryhalloffame.com> (48/48), delay=00:00:04, xdelay=00:00:04, mailer=relay, pri=120851, relay=aspmx3.googlemail.com. [72.14.213.27], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jul  2 22:47:27 culinaryhalloffame sendmail[21272]: p632lNkV021270: p632lRkV021272: DSN: User unknown
Jul  2 22:47:27 culinaryhalloffame sendmail[21272]: p632lRkV021272: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=32102, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

Any hints? I don't want SMTP authentication. I just want the outgoing email sent to Gmail instead of getting intercepted locally.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MAIL_HUB`](http://sendmail.org./m4/masquerading_relaying.html#MAIL_HUB) seems better for your needs than `LUSER_RELAY`.  You do, after all, state that *all* accounts are on Google Apps.

Comment: Thanks JdeBP. I actually figured that out after the post. For reference, the line was: 
  
define(`MAIL_HUB', `myhost.com.')dnl

Then recompiled with:  

m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf

And restarted the service.